# Thriller sub-genre

Tags: fiction, genre, thriller

Is there a genre that could be called "Safe Thriller"? It seems that all thriller novels are R rated. A PG rated thriller could still be engaging and serious without gross content. Similar to a "Cozy Mystery"?

Comment: Look at Middle Grade detective novels such as *The Three Investigators*, *Famous Five*, and all the more recent examples.

Comment: There is plenty of audience for this.  You can aim it at children, or you can aim it at adults, by including humor, or you can include a cat (Lillian Jackson Braun).  If you want to find a specific sub-genre, find one example, and then let Amazon propose similar titles.

Answer (score 1):

This is the sort of question you can best answer with a stroll down to your local bookstore. But consider: thrills come from danger. You need to be strapped in to ride the roller coaster. A book let's you take a thrill ride with the safety harness off. The roller coaster is probably the preferred source of safe thrills.

Answer (score 1):

Goosebumps would probably be your closest bet to what you are looking for.  It is children/teen series that does a PG horror/thriller story.  I use to read them a ton growing up and I hate horror or thrillers for that matter.